# How to change the global font of a WinUI3 App?

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

I want to know How to change the global font of a WinUI3 App?

I have tried this way, but it didn't work.

In App.xaml file:

```
<Style TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/fonts/OppoSans.ttf#Oppo Sans" />
</Style>
```

In csproj file:

```
<Content Include="fonts\OppoSans.ttf">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70371593/how-do-i-change-the-default-font-of-my-winui-application

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could follow the following steps:

1, Add the fonts .tff file to myapp/Assets/Fonts (here I use the DancingScript font)

[image]

2, Add resource dictionary in app.xaml:

```
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <FontFamily x:Key="MyCustomFont">/Assets/Fonts/DancingScript-Bold.ttf#Dancing Script</FontFamily>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MyCustomFont}"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

And then You could use the custom font as the default font:

[image]

Comment: It didn't work. Should I add something to the csproj file?

Comment: Have you followed my steps in a Blank app? You just need add the code that I provided to the App.xaml file (after `<!-- Other app resources here -->`)

Comment: @CherryStach Have you got any updates about this issue?

Comment: Not working. I just added the following codes to the App.xaml file. And in the MainWindow, I write like yours.

I've uploaded the Project file to [Github](https://github.com/yuzh0816/temporary):

Answer (score 0):

You can change font by overriding default font.
Copy your font to Assets/Fonts folder and make sure build action for font is set to `Content`
Then write this code in App.xaml:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/OppoSans.ttf#Oppo Sans</FontFamily>
```